# What is the best method to load a Jupyter notebook session into Spyder?

Tags: python, jupyter, spyder

Edit: See Spyder Notebook Plugin... https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-notebook

---

I would like to load a Jupyter notebook into Spyder and activate the current Jupyter Python kernel in an Spyder Ipython console.  I was hoping this would allow me to use the Spyder editor, console and variable explorer whilst developing in Jupyter. Using the code below in Jupyter, I have been able to load up a converted notebook. In addition, I can open the current kernel in a new console manually. However, the variable explorer doesn't display variables from the connected console.

I would like to:

1) From Jupyter, automatically open the current Jupyter kernel in the Spyder IPython Console
2) Get the Spyder variable explorer to work with a connected kernel

Any ideas? Does anyone have a better method than that listed below?

---

### Open Jupyter notebook and kernel in Spyder:

#### Get current notebook name

```
%%javascript
var nb = IPython.notebook;
var kernel = IPython.notebook.kernel;
var commandFileName = "theNotebook = " + "'"+ nb.notebook_path +"'";
kernel.execute(commandFileName);
```

#### Convert notebook to plain python script

```
get_ipython().system('jupyter nbconvert --to script "' + theNotebook + '"')
```

#### Open python script in Spyder

```
get_ipython().system('spyder "' + theNotebook.replace('.ipynb', '.py') + '"')
```

#### Get kernel json connection file

```
import ipykernel
print("Copy and paste this into Spyder diaolgue box:\nConsoles~'Connect to an existing kernel':\n")
print(ipykernel.connect.get_connection_file())
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*) This will be solved once we make our own [Notebook plugin](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-notebook) to start Spyder kernels.

We're working right now to release a first version of that plugin with good desktop integration. Then we'll proceed to integrate it with the other Spyder plugins (such as the Variable Explorer) and for that we need to make the notebook to start Spyder kernels.

Comment: How is it coming along?

Comment: Our notebook plugin is not very discoverable, but it should be docked next to the Editor. Look for a tab called `Notebook` and press it.

Comment: This post is more than 2 years old.
Is the notebook plugin also needed for the current version? (this is what I get:
`C:\> conda list <cr>
... <cr>
spyder                    3.3.6                    py37_1    conda-forge <cr>
spyder-kernels            0.5.2                    py37_0    defaults <cr>
...`
)

Comment: It is very cool. I have been using it and absolutely loved it. Lately, I updated spyder to 5.0, sadly spyder notebook is not compatible with Spyder 5.0. Hoping that the team works on this soon.

Comment: Yeah, it'll be updated in the month or two.

Answer (score 6):

To install this plugin, you can use either pip or conda package managers, as follows:

Using conda (the recommended way!):

**conda install spyder-notebook -c spyder-ide**

Using pip:

**pip install spyder-notebook**

Web: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-notebook

Comment: I installed plugin (on Spyder 4.1.5) and it is not clear how to create jupyter notebook (it does not show under File menu), nor I can open previously saved notebooks (they open as xml)

Comment: As already commented above: "Notebook plugin is not so discoverable. Look for a tab called Notebook (View->Panes->Notebook)". It will appear at the bottom next to the Editor page. You can open the notebook file from there only(top right corner).  I don't recommend Notebook here coz it is just light version so better go for Notebook Web version.

Answer (score 0):

use any IDE or editor within anaconda interpreter i use it within pycharm and performance well